Paid amount via QR code scan to merchant, next my money was lost
Last Saturday i paid amount via CRED App QR code scan to merchant, the money was debit from account but the receiver not received the amount. If ask the CRED customer care support they said money was successfully transferred to he merchant but merchant told we are not received the money.
Now where is my???
I was report NPCI, still not get my money back, any one any idea how to get my money.

Did you send it with the Gooble Grape version?  It's known to have that issue.  For details, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FRksnk8sG30 (NSFWEIOH)

I am talking about CRED payment Gateway : https://cred.club/

How are we able to answer this question?  I think CRED customer service and your bank are more apt to do so.  It is also possible that the merchant is lying.

Okay, Already raised ticket, meanwhile i am asking if anyone faced same kind of solution, maybe i will get some idea. Thanks.

Has the payment shown up on your bank or credit card website yet?  You may be able to cancel the transaction and start a new one, or make the payment another way.

Be cautious about involving your bank unless you intend to initiate a chargeback (which may cause Cred to ban you).  Bank customer support can be a bit trigger happy.
